# Использование статичной структуры в нескольких файлах

Tags: c++

Есть 3 файла:
test.h:

```
static struct {
        int value = 99;
} test;
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "test.h"

void t() {
        test.value = 33;
}

void t2();

int main() {
        std::cout << test.value << std::endl;
        test.value = 66;
        std::cout << test.value << std::endl;
        t();
        std::cout << test.value << std::endl;
        t2();
        std::cout << test.value << std::endl;
}
```

test2.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "test.h"

void t2() {
        std::cout << "t2 called" << std::endl;
        test.value = 0;
}
```

Компиляция:

```
ccache g++ -c -Wall test.cpp -o test.o
ccache g++ -c -Wall test2.cpp -o test2.o
ccache g++  test.o test2.o -o test
```

Вывод:

```
99
66
33
t2 called
33
```

Почему? Что я делаю не так?
Я ожидаю вывод:

```
99
66
33
t2 called
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря слову `static` в каждом .cpp-файле имеется *своя* переменная `test`. Поэтому `t2()` изменяет `test` в `test2.cpp`, но не в `test.cpp`.

Если вам нужна одна и та же переменная во всех файлах - я бы объявил в .h-файле

```
struct Test {
        int value = 99;
};

extern Test test;
```

А в *одном* из .cpp-файлов - саму

```
Test test;
```

Начиная с C++17 можно также для получения того же результата использовать в .h-файле вместо `static` ключевое слово `inline`.

Comment: Спасибо. Только с inline у меня всё равно не работает. А можно-ли использовать анонимную структуру с `extern`? UPD: Ммм.. inline заработал, когда я тип объявил...